# How to show a regularly spaced subset of the axis labels on the axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with discrete labels, each label is a text in the form of `"hh:mm"`. I have 4 labels per hour, i.e. `"09:00"`, `"09:15"`, `"09:30"`, `"09:45"`, from `"00.00"` to `"23:45"`. So, 96 possible label values. 
I want to show only one label per hour, so `"09:00"`, `"10:00"`, and so on, and omit `"09:15"`, `"09:30"`, `"09:45"`, in order to have a clearer plot. I tried in many ways to use the function `scale_x_discrete` as in `scale_x_discrete(breaks = lab$Time)`
where `lab` is a vector containing only the labels I want to print, but I always get `"invalid argument"` error.

```
head(lab)
    Time
73 00:00
77 01:00
81 02:00
85 03:00
89 04:00
93 05:00
```

Comment: you should add a reproducible example so wan can play with it.

Comment: In `scale_x_discrete` you need  `breaks` and `labels` parameters. See my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you. You should set `breaks` and `labels` parameters and everything should work:

```
# simple data
 df<-data.frame(labs=c("00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45"),
           val=1:8,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# select labels to show
df2<-df %>% 
group_by(labs) %>%
mutate(gr= length(grep(":00",labs))) %>%
filter(gr==1) %>%
select(labs) %>%
as.data.frame()

#     labs
#  1 00:00
#  2 01:00

ggplot(df,aes(x=labs,y=val))+geom_point()+
 scale_x_discrete(breaks=df2$labs,labels=df2$labs)
```

[image]

Comment: If so, please accept the answer and vote, that everyone else would know is useful :)